# SQL Selecting A Range Of Data According To Sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

So I have this problem where I am trying to select a range of data for this sql that will run monthly. Basically I have this field Date_OF_Entry that records dates as 01-Jan-15

Now I will be running this script twice a month at the 16th to capture all the data from the 15th back to the 1st. I will also then run the script at the 1st of the next month to capture all data from the end of the month to the 16th.

Any help is appreciated.

What I am doing now.

Where DATE_OF_ENTRY > sysdate-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROUND(date,'MM') Rounds down to the 15th, and up from the 16th.

So WHERE ROUND(DATE_OF_ENTRY,'MM') = ROUND(sysdate-1,'MM') will - on the 16th - round sydate and the 1-15th down to the start of the month, and, on the 1st will round everything from the 16th up.

Be carefull though as on the 1st if any new records have been added where date_of_entry = the 1st, they would get bumped down into last month's end of month group.

So, WHERE ROUND(DATE_OF_ENTRY,'MM') = ROUND(sysdate-1,'MM') AND date_of_entry < trunc(sysdate) should clear that up.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better for use of an index?: `date_of_entry > round(sysdate-1, 'MM') and date_of_entry < trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: Ok so while testing these solutions out today since it's the 16th I noticed that Michael's solution still pulls data from the prior month before the 1st of the current month. Shawn's works expect it doesn't get the 1st of the month data, but it gets everything else correctly.